# Bootstrap pull-left pull right

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I just cannot get my head around using these two and how they work. For example:

I have a single row and a single column and within I want to align one item left and one item right.

The following puts "left align me" on the LHS and "right align me" on the RHS but not on the same row with each other. I want the text to be on the same row. I can do this with a table but want to learn how to do it properly. What am I missing?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      Sidebar
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <div>
        left align me
      </div>
      <div class="pull-right">
        right align me
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, sorry i can't understand. What you want ? please share image or snippet.

Comment: I have improved the html above. Within a column I wish to align one item left and another right and have them on the same line as each other.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ma6aq4mx/)**, I think this is what you are wanting to do here.

Just using a `div` with no given width the `div` will take the full width.
I think you meant to be using the class `col-xs-push-xx`. But to use this you also need to give each div some width.

[image]

Comment: Hi and thanks for the help. The last example above is what I am seeking to achieve however I want to align text left & right within a column.

Comment: Hi, for the text alignment also see the top 3 line examples for the classes to align text.